# Как сделать безопасный сайт?

Tags: php, безопасность, mysql

Здравствуйте всем!

Я делаю сайт на mysql и php. Есть код, но я знаю, что без настроек безопасности сайт может быть взломан. Какие файлы нужно добавлять для ограничения доступа. Буду признателен любой информации на эту тему - можно и ссылки.

Я теоретически понимаю, что наверное нужно всю структуру по папкам разложить и каждой папке какой-то особый доступ сделать. Хотелось бы понятные инструкции для новичка в этом деле. В деле безопасности. Спасибо.

Такие 3 базовых элемента: сделать первое, второе и третье и твой сайт будет безопасен максимально. Я знаю что на 100 процентов защитить нельзя. Но максимальную защиту выстроить хотелось бы. Какое шифрование лучше для пароля? Можно ли например пароль от базы хранить в md5 или другой кодировке?

Читал что пароль для доступа к базе нужно как-то секретно хранить. Как это нужно делать?
И я правильно понимаю, что если взломают доступ к файлам сайта - то сама база будет не тронутой или как?

Comment: я в это вообще нечего не понимаю, но разве мало таких статей в интернете? разве сначала сложно посмотреть самому, а уже потом, если что-то не понятно или сомнительно спросить? Или разве в формате "вопрос-ответ" можно получить хорошую информацию о безопасности сайта?

Comment: Как сделать безопасный сайт?

Не писать его вообще, он будет настолько безопасным что никто его не сможет взломать :)

Comment: Shrek, отличный комментарий!!!! ))))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> каждой папке какой-то особый доступ
> сделать

К примеру в файлах `.tpl` в папке `templates/tpl` могут выполняться php скрипты на примере использования `Smarty`. Для этого в папку tpl добавить файл `.htaccess` и записать в него следующее

```
<Files ~ "\.(tpl)$">
Deny from all 
</Files>
```

> Какое шифрование лучше для пароля?

[sha1](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sha1.php)

Во всех `php` файлах которые не вызываются из адресной строки к примеру `index.php` или `contacts.php` добавить

```
defined("MY CMS") or die("WTF);
```

а в файлы которые вызываются из адресной строки

```
define("MY CMS", true);
```

Узнать что такое регулярные выражения и как используя их отвергать `POST` и `GET` запросы, злые `COOKIES` и даже `FILES` если там присутствует что-то вроде

```
UNION|OUTFILE|SELECT|ALTER|INSERT|DROP|FROM|WHERE|UPDATE
```

З.Ы. Честно говоря писать можно **целый день** как защитить свой сайт от того что его нагнут. Расковыряй удобную для себя `open source CMS` и посмотри как что устроино!

З.Ы.Ы В одном месте всего не прочесть, и за одинь день всего не узнать! Все приходит со временем и с опытом!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но я же никакой CMS не использую, а сам сайт пишу.

Comment: CMS использует скрипты. Скрипты написаны на php. Вбольшинстве средствами php ты собираешся делать защиту. Вот и посмотри примерно как там что реализовано. Речь не идет о конкретной CMS или о самописном сайте, а конкретно о возможностях реализации защиты!

Comment: Интересно, чем же sha1 лучше md5? Время подбора практически одинаковое, md5 даже дольше...

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, буду смотреть)

Comment: Еще хотел узнать только ли через php делают защиту или можно еще как-то защищать? можете ли дать какие-нибудь ссылки о защите сайта?

Comment: @qwerty17, Google даст немало ссылок))

Answer (score 1):

Защита пароля базы, на случай если PHP ляжет.
В `index.php` где нужно соединение с базой вставляем

```
include_once('../db-site.php');
```

Файл `db-site.php` размещаем перед корнем сайта, в самом файле выполняем соединение с базой.

Теперь если у вас ляжет PHP, и посетителю откроется текстовый вид вашего движка, никто не увидит пароль к вашей базе.

И, да, на joomla это не поможет, у них там в файле `config.php` (точно не помню название) всё есть.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно этот файл php где идет соединение с базой куда-нибудь поглубже в папку запихать и закрыть к ней доступ или так никто не делает?
И в самом деле я удивляюсь в джумле в корне сайта в конфиге все пароли записаны. мне кажется легко их достать.

и еще я не понял что значит "Файл db-site.php размещаем перед корнем сайта"
у меня код такой:
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","mysqltest","1234");  mysql_select_db("sql_test",$db);
не понял куда строчку include_once('../db-site.php') вставлять?